# Properly Use a Loop to Display Numbers and their Squares

Tags: python

I am trying to get this program to display the numbers and their squares like so

5 25

6 36

7 49

8 64

9 81
but the program will not display either the squares or the numbers.I've attempted to create a list for the number variable but unfortunately to no avail.

```
# This program uses a loop to display a
# table of numbers and their squares.

# Get the starting value.
print('This program displays a list of numbers')
print('and their squares.')
start = int(input('Enter the starting number: '))

# Get the ending limit.
end = int(input('How high should I go? '))

# Print the table headings.
print()
print('Number\tSquare')
print('--------------')


# Print the numbers and their squares.
for number in range(end, start + 1):
    square = number**2
    print(number, '\t', square)
```

Comment: Your arguments in `range` seem backwards. You should be going from low to high.

Comment: `range` is a bit odd. The interpretation of the first argument changes depending on how many arguments you pass. With only one argument, the first argument is the upper end of the range (with an implicit start at 0). With two arguments, it becomes the explicit starting point and the second argument is now the upper end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing your range statement: range(start, end + 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your code as is if you use the range() function's third (optional) argument: range(start, end, step). Set step=-1 (minus one).